# How to pull the Contact Details of Amazon Connect using Lambda Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, lambda

How to pull the Contact Details of Amazon Connect using Lambda Python
like Contact ID , phone number.

{
"Contact" : {
"Arn" : "**",
"Id" : "***",
"InitiationMethod" : "OUTBOUND",
"Channel" : "VOICE",
"AgentInfo" : {
"Id" : "**",
"ConnectedToAgentTimestamp" : "***"
},
"InitiationTimestamp" : "**",
"DisconnectTimestamp" : "**",
"LastUpdateTimestamp" : "**"
}
}

Please help.

Thank you